# How do I use cross_val_score to fit my test data?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am trying to understand the use of cross_val_score(). I understand how it works and all, and its purpose. but  let's look at the simple example

```
reg = LinearRegression()
cv_scores = cross_val_score(reg, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
cv_scores = cross_val_score(reg, X_train, y_train, cv=10)
```

assuming that a get a mean score of say .91 and .84 with cv=5 and cv=10 respectively. How do I use that information to fit my test data?

The one way I can think of is use the best value for CV i.e. 5 in this case in a GridSearchCV and fit the training data and predict the test data. Is that right? and if so can perform that task without using GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to realize here is that the cv parameter **does not** refer to your model, but rather to how you are going to perform cross-validation. In this case, you are comparing 5-fold vs 10-fold cross-validation.

Remember that what you are trying to do with cross-validation is to estimate the error when applying your method to the general population. In the case of least squares linear regression, Leave-one-out CV error will be asymptotically the CV with least bias + variance. However in practice the difference won't be too much, this mostly just matters with small sample sizes.

**Now, why** do you need an estimate of the "test error"? Because when you solve most models, what you are trying to minimize is precisely the error function when applied to the training data, so if you aren't careful and your model is too complex you will get great results on your training data, but not in the population. CV is done to make sure this isn't happening. In Linear Regression, usually you do CV by varying the **number of features** (forward selection, or use something like lasso if you don't mind paying some cost in bias error), and fix  cv=5 (or 10, it doesn't really matter in most cases)

Comment: thanks @Juan Carlos Ramirez, I think my confusion was more around does cross validation process train our training set any which way different to make it more robust to deal with test data and I believe the answer is no. cross validation by itself doesnt reduce overfitting for instance, but just lets you know how the model if expected to perform in unseen data, but running the process on training data (kfold etc etc). Would you agree with this assertion ?

Comment: Exactly, one of its applications is to diagnose overfitting, another is to choose between models. The naive approach is to use the model that gives you the least training error, but this might just be due to your model having too many degrees of freedom(if you do linear regression with n features on n datapoints your training error is going to be 0!) so it is not a reliable approach.

Comment: btw along the same line, how is Lasso different from LassoCV. if I have these two codes. ```reg = LassoCV(cv=5, random_state=0).fit(X, y)``` and  ``` reg1 = Lasso().fit(X,y)```. More importantly, if I use reg.predict() and reg1.predict() on same out of sample data, I get different scores. why is that the case?

Comment: LassoCV automatically chooses the regularization penalty by doing crossvalidation and choosing the best model.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Machine Learning where assessing the performance of your model is part of the fun.

`k` is in general a hyperparameter set by you, but how to choose it? Well, there are no exact law's for that. Rule of thumb is: `k = min(10, sqrt(n))`, where `n` is the number of data points you have.

More interesting what is the implication of `k` being small or large? Small `k` (e.g. 2) means we suffer a lot of data (50% of it) for validation, out model might not capture the whole complexity of our data, this leads to increased test bias (model is underfitting). Large `k` implies we are not able to trust our error estimate from the (small) test data set since it may not be representative for the whole complexity of our data. This leads to high test variance.

Here is a good blog post which explains everything in more detail: https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/cross-validation-and-the-bias-variance-tradeoff-for-dummies/

In you specific case I would recommend not to look only at the mean of your cross_val_score, but also the the standard deviation. This will give you a more insightful view on how your model might perform on test data. GridSearchCV itself is a tool to find hyperparameters for your model, the value of `k` is so to say a hyper-hyperparameter.

Comment: thanks @Tinu, that was useful. My confusion is how does it help overcome overfitting. I believe it would be fair to say that it actually doesn't prevent overfitting, but simply helps in identifying any case of overfitting.  i.e. will just tell you how the model will do in unseen data. is that right?